# Laravel library causes Google Sheets API errors on Ubuntu

Tags: laravel

I have the Google API on my Laravel v8 site:

```
composer require revolution/laravel-google-sheets

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PulkitJalan\Google\GoogleServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

I set up the credentials and have it working on my testing server which is a Lightsail/Bitnami server.

I pulled my branch on my real server which is Lightsail/Ubuntu. I ran `composer install` and I double checked both servers have the same packages/versions installed. They have the same data in the `.env` file.

Now when I am attempting to connect to the spreadsheet I am getting this error:

> Argument 1 passed to PulkitJalan\Google\Client::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /vendor/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient/src/GoogleServiceProvider.php on line 31"

It would be this line:

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/google.php', 'google');

        $this->app->bind('PulkitJalan\Google\Client', function ($app) {
            return new Client($app['config']['google']);
        });
    }
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Your question refers to using composer to install [`revolution/laravel-google-sheets`](https://packagist.org/packages/revolution/laravel-google-sheets), which references [this repo](https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets), but you're running the `php artisan` instructions of [a different repo](https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient). Is there a reason for that?

Comment: One package requires the other, but that was just for reference on which packages I am using. Both are in my composer file and installed.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to make that clear to other readers. Have you followed the instructions of the first repo: https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets ?

Comment: `$app['config']['google']` is giving you `null`, howeverrrr we never ever edit code in the `vendor` directory, so... follow your stacktrace in the laravel.log to your own code, see where you forgot to add your api key. Update your original question